# Automatic Memcaching On Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

I have got to learn about Memcache recently. I have a project in PHP Codeigniter. So, what I have understood memcache does is, it stores the result of database query, and if the result is needed again, it provides the result immediately instead of running the query again which makes the application fast. So I tried to implement memcache. Then I explored that I have to manually store a cache for every query. My application has hundreds of query function, it is almost impossible for me to implement memcache for each on of them.

Is there any way by which all the queries will be stored to memcache and when a result will be needed, it will provide data from memcache and if not available in memcache then run the database query and store it to memcache for further use?

I don't know if I have been able to make you understand what I exactly want, please ask me in reply if anything seems unclear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want a middleware for applying to specific route sets? If so, CodeIgniter provides hooks system https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html (Similar to Laravel's middleware). After performing your query functions, you can easily implement a caching mechanism via hooks. But you need to find a middleware/hook(or build from scratch) for your solving specific problem. Hope I could help you.